# Choose default program to open the shortcut in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-management, shortcuts

Is there a way to specify which program should open the shortcut.

Take browsers for example. My default browser is Firefox. I have some important shortcuts on my desktop that don't perform well in Firefox, so I want them to open in Internet Explorer.

***Important !***
I know there are other ways of doing this. Such as creating favorites. But I need this feature also for other files, not only internet shortcuts.

I like to work with specific programs for specific files. So please try to help me with the problem of opening different files in different programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append the URL to a shortcut to the browser of your choice.

For example, my default browser is Chrome but I have a desktop shortcut to Outlook Web Access in Internet Explorer. The Shortcut target looks like:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.example.com/path/
```

You can do the same with document files:

```
%windir%\system32\notepad.exe d:\spreadsheet.csv
```

(quotes needed if there are spaces in the path.)

The easiest way to do this is to copy a shortcut to the program of choice from the Start menu to your desktop, right-click it and select 'Properties' and add the file path or URL to the 'Target' field.

Comment: Thank you I like this solution, it is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Low-Tech solution: Drag the file on the application icon you can also put on your desktop.

Or use Right click → Open with → ...

Otherwise there is [Browser Chooser](http://browserchooser.codeplex.com/), but that's not for arbitrary files, just stuff browsers open.

Comment: This solution is good, but it is not hard-coded in the shortcut. It is a good solution tho.

Comment: @Saif: Ok, misunderstood your question a little, then :)

Answer (score 0):

As been said, right click, open with. But then, besides hitting "Browse..." button to choose the folder and exe, be sure the checkbox in that first screen which says "use allways this software to open..." (something like that) is checked.

That's to open always that file format with certain software. If you want a file to be opened with a different software than other files of the same format, I can only think of right click on empty space, create new shortcut, dialog where you can browse (or paste the url of the folder, then just choose  the exe) till your exe, and select it. Is actually making a shortcut.If is just a url,  paste it in the first window of new/create shortcut wizzard, that appeared when right clicking on desktop or empty folder space.

Answer (score -1):

i was able to do

right-click --> New --> Shortcut

for the location of item enter:  "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.example.com/path/